# Rule to check characters

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to create a rule which will find lowercase letters and invalid characters and then display a message saying 'Please input again'. I have written the following code but it is not working: 
Only these characters are allowed = **ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789**

```
public static String LowerCase() {
    Scanner Input  =new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input two words: ");
String GetInput = Input.nextLine();
System.out.println("");
return GetInput;
}

boolean validinput=false;
{
        while 
            {
            validinput==false;
            validinput==true;
            }
        for (x=0, x<english.length();x++)
        {
            (check_lowercase(
                    if english.charAt(x))); 
            validinput=false;
}
if (validinput==false);
    System.out.println("Please input again");
if (validinput==true);
System.out.println("");
```

}

Thank you

Comment: _but it is not working_: Does it even compile?

Comment: And what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] h) {
    String input = getInput();
    while (!input.matches("[A-Z0-9]+")) {
        System.out.println("Please input again");
        input = getInput();
    }
    System.out.println("your input : " + input);

}

public static String getInput() {
    Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input two words: ");
    return Input.nextLine();
}
```

Only these characters are allowed = `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789` is written easily in terms of `[A-Z0-9]`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am getting error on void...its saying 'syntax error on "void" @ expected...what does this mean?

Comment: this code includes any syntax error.I think you wrote code at wrong place.Please look java class structure.

Answer (score 1):

Check the acsii value of the caracter:

```
    boolean validinput = false;
    char c = english.charAt(x);

    if((c>64&&c<91) || (c>47&&c<58)) 
        validinput=true;
```

65-90 are all uppercase letters and 48-57 are all numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.contains()`  or `String.indexOf()` methods

```
String allowedStr="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

char c = english.charAt(x);
```

---

```
 validInput=allowedStr.contains(Character.toString(c));
```

or

```
int index=allowedStr.indexOf(c);
if(index!=-1)
    validInput=true;
```